# Tkinter application to manage school tasks

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, tkinter, to-do-list

I'm a beginner in OOP programming and I'm wondering what is the best way to put all the windows and functions of a window application in the code.
My biggest questions are:

- Am I using classes and function in the right way?
- There is an efficient way to create windows and widgets?
- Why do I see so many peoples inheriting from `tk.Frame` in window classes?
- In the example of application given in Tkinter documentation, they put the widgets inside a method called "create_widgets", is this recommended instead put them in the `__init__` method?

I translated the interface from the original Brazilian Portuguese before posting the question here.

```
"""Componentes Curriculares V0.1.

This program is meant to be a task manager to your School Year.
It is composed by various functions such as:
-List of all your tasks and tests, and a complete school report based on these
tasks. (This last one still is a work in progress.)
You can also add your topics for each subject that you are having along the
year.
The main language of the interface is Portuguese and their source code was
written in English.
Python 3.7 is the current version.
"""

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from datetime import datetime
import pickle
import getpass

# Standard variables used for multiple widgets.
fontlab_std = 'Tahoma 12 bold'
fontbut_std = 'Tahoma 9'
bg_std = 'cornsilk2'
hover_std = 'Created by Wilson Cazarré - 3° Mecatrônica. Alpha 0.1'
icon_windows = 'book.ico'

my_subjects = ['LPL',
               'Matemática',
               'Biologia',
               'Geografia',
               'História',
               'Química',
               'Física',
               'Filosofia',
               'Sociologia',
               'Educação Física',
               'Inglês',
               'Tecnologia de Manufatura 3',
               'Linguagem de Programação Aplicada a Mecatrônica',
               'Automação e Instrumentação Industrial 3',
               'Microcontroladores',
               'Tecnologia de Qualidade e processos',
               'Robótica e Manufatura Flexível',
               'Eletrônica Industrial e de Potência',
               'Planejamento e Desenvolvimento do Trabalho de Conclusão de '
               'Curso']
grades = ['MB',
          'B',
          'R',
          'I']

days = list(range(1, 32))
mouths = ['Janeiro',
          'Fevereiro',
          'Março',
          'Abril',
          'Maio',
          'Junho',
          'Julho',
          'Agosto',
          'Setembro',
          'Outubro',
          'Novembro',
          'Dezembro']
years = list(range(2019, 2030))
weekdays = ['Segunda',
            'Terça-feira',
            'Quarta-feira',
            'Quinta-feira',
            'Sexta-feira',
            'Sábado',
            'Domingo']


# ---------------------------------


def load_pickle(file) -> list:
    try:
        with open(file, 'rb') as infile:
            tasks_objects = pickle.load(infile)
            tasks_objects.sort(key=lambda task: task.full_date)
        return tasks_objects
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return []
    except PermissionError:
        messagebox.showerror('Acesso Negado',
                             'Erro ao ler o arquivo. Iniciar como administrador')


def dump_pickle(file, obj):
    with open(file, 'wb') as outfile:
        pickle.dump(obj, outfile, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)


# --------------------------------- Custom Widgets with default option


class MyButton(tk.Button):
    """Create a custom button widget, with default options."""

    def __init__(self, master=None, hovertext=None, **kw):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, master=master, **kw)
        self.configure(font=fontbut_std, relief='groove')  # Default options
        if hovertext is not None:
            self.bind('<Enter>', lambda x: self.on_hover(hovertext))
            self.bind('<Leave>', lambda x: self.on_hover(hover_std))

    @staticmethod
    def on_hover(text):
        app.hover_box.configure(text=text)


class MyLabel(tk.Label):
    """Create a custom button widget, with default options."""

    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf=None, **kw):
        tk.Label.__init__(self, master=master, cnf=cnf, **kw)
        self.configure(bg=bg_std)


# --------------------------------- All windows, and the Task Class


class Task:
    """Objects listed in the 'MainWindow.tasks_widget'.

    Tasks are saved in the following lists:
    list: open_tasks: tasks not completed.
    list: ended_tasks: tasks completed.
    """

    def __init__(self, subject, title, day, month, year, category,
                 description=None, is_done=False, grade=None):
        self.subject = subject
        self.title = title
        self.day = day
        self.month = month
        self.year = year
        self.description = description
        self.is_done = is_done
        self.grade = grade
        self.category = category
        self.full_date = datetime(int(self.year), mouths.index(self.month) + 1,
                                  int(self.day))
        self.weekday = self.full_date.weekday()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}: "{}" ' \
               'para o dia {}/{}/{} ({})'.format(self.subject, self.category,
                                                 self.title, self.day,
                                                 self.month, self.year,
                                                 weekdays[self.
                                                 weekday])

    def str_task_complete(self):
        return '{}: "{}" Menção: {} - {}/{}/{}'.format(self.category,
                                                       self.title,
                                                       self.grade,
                                                       self.day,
                                                       self.month,
                                                       self.year)


class MainWindow:
    """Create the first window of the program.

    self.add_button - invoke AddTaskWindow -> create a task object.
    self.done_button - invoke EndTaskWindow  -> set the task object as done.
    """

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        # Master window configs
        master.title('Componentes Curriculares')
        master.minsize(width=900, height=520)
        master.maxsize(width=900, height=520)
        master.geometry('+360+100')
        master.iconbitmap(icon_windows)
        master.configure(bg=bg_std)

        # Setup Widgets
        self.title = MyLabel(self.master, text='My Subjects',
                             font='Tahoma 15 bold',
                             bg=bg_std,
                             fg='DeepSkyBlue2',
                             anchor='e',
                             width=67)
        self.tasks_title = MyLabel(self.master,
                                   text='Tasks, tests and events',
                                   font='Tahoma 12 bold')

        self.tasks_widget = tk.Listbox(self.master,
                                       width=100, height=25,
                                       relief='solid',
                                       highlightthickness=0)

        for task in open_tasks:
            self.tasks_widget.insert('end', task)

        self.tasks_widget.bind('<Enter>', lambda x: MyButton.on_hover
        ('Double click to set a task as done.'))
        self.tasks_widget.bind('<Leave>', lambda x: MyButton.on_hover
        (hover_std))

        self.tasks_widget.bind('<Double-Button-1>',
                               lambda x: EndTaskWindow(tk.Toplevel(),
                                                       self.tasks_widget.
                                                       curselection()))

        self.add_button = MyButton(self.master,
                                   hovertext='Add a task.',
                                   text='+',
                                   fg='green3',
                                   command=self.open_task_window,
                                   width=1)
        self.sub_button = MyButton(self.master,
                                   hovertext='Remove current selected task.',
                                   text='-',
                                   fg='red',
                                   command=lambda: self.delete_task
                                   (self.tasks_widget.curselection()),
                                   width=1)

        self.done_button = MyButton(self.master,
                                    hovertext='Finalizar tarefa e registar a '
                                              'menção.',
                                    text='Complete',
                                    command=lambda: EndTaskWindow(
                                        tk.Toplevel(),
                                        self.tasks_widget.curselection()))

        self.view_button = MyButton(self.master,
                                    hovertext='Show task information.',
                                    text='Open',
                                    command=lambda: ViewTaskWindow(
                                        tk.Toplevel(),
                                        self.tasks_widget.curselection()))

        self.tasks_widget.bind('<Delete>', lambda x: self.delete_task(
            self.tasks_widget.curselection()))

        self.hover_box = tk.Label(self.master, text=hover_std, bg='white',
                                  anchor='w')

        self.combo_title = MyLabel(self.master,
                                   text='Show subjects information:',
                                   font='Tahoma 9 bold')
        self.combo_subjects = ttk.Combobox(self.master, values=my_subjects,
                                           width=30)
        self.combo_confirm = MyButton(self.master, text='Open',
                                      hovertext='Exibir janela de informações '
                                                'da matéria selecionada',
                                      command=lambda: SubjectWindow(
                                          tk.Toplevel(),
                                          self.combo_subjects.get()))
        self.combo_confirm['font'] = 'Tahoma 9'

        # Place Widgets
        self.title.place(x=10, y=5)

        self.tasks_title.place(x=10, y=30)
        self.tasks_widget.place(x=10, y=58)

        self.add_button.place(x=10, y=463)
        self.sub_button.place(x=28, y=463)
        self.done_button.place(x=46, y=463)
        self.view_button.place(x=110, y=463)

        self.combo_title.place(x=630, y=180)
        self.combo_subjects.place(x=630, y=200)
        self.combo_confirm.place(x=835, y=198)

        self.hover_box.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')

    def open_task_window(self):
        """Hey"""
        window2 = tk.Toplevel()
        self.add_button['state'] = 'disable'
        self.sub_button['state'] = 'disable'
        self.done_button['state'] = 'disable'
        self.view_button['state'] = 'disable'
        self.combo_confirm['state'] = 'disable'
        self.taskwindow = AddTaskWindow(window2)

    def delete_task(self, index):
        delete_box = 'no'
        if index != ():
            delete_box = messagebox.askquestion('Deletar Tarefa',
                                                'Deletar tarefa selecionada?')
        if delete_box == 'yes':
            self.tasks_widget.delete(index)
            open_tasks.pop(index[0])
            with open(file_open_tasks, 'wb') as outfile:
                pickle.dump(open_tasks, outfile, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)


class AddTaskWindow:
    """Launch the window for create a task in
    MainWindow.tasks_widget(tk.Listbox)

    self.register_button -> self.create_task -> Task -> Create task object.
    """

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        app.done_button['state'] = 'disable'
        master.title('Criar Tarefa')
        master.geometry('600x400+500+200')
        master.iconbitmap(icon_windows)
        master.configure(bg=bg_std)
        master.attributes('-topmost', True)
        master.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.close_window)
        master.focus_force()
        self.radio_var = tk.StringVar()

        # Setup Widgets
        self.title_radio = MyLabel(self.master, text='Task type:',
                                   font='Tahoma 8 bold')
        self.radio1 = tk.Radiobutton(self.master, text='Test',
                                     variable=self.radio_var, value='Prova',
                                     bg=bg_std,
                                     activebackground=bg_std)
        self.radio2 = tk.Radiobutton(self.master, text='Homework',
                                     variable=self.radio_var, value='Trabalho',
                                     bg=bg_std,
                                     activebackground=bg_std)
        self.radio3 = tk.Radiobutton(self.master, text='Other',
                                     variable=self.radio_var,
                                     value='Outro(Sem menção)', bg=bg_std,
                                     activebackground=bg_std)

        self.title_entry = MyLabel(self.master, text='Task title:',
                                   font='Tahoma 8 bold')
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.master, width=60, relief='groove')

        self.title_combo_subjects = MyLabel(self.master,
                                            text='Task subject:',
                                            font='Tahoma 8 bold')
        self.combo_subjects = ttk.Combobox(self.master, values=my_subjects,
                                           width=60)

        self.title_date = MyLabel(self.master, text='Task date:',
                                  font='Tahoma 8 bold')
        self.combo_day = ttk.Combobox(self.master, values=days, width=3)
        self.combo_day.current(days.index(datetime.now().day))

        self.combo_mouth = ttk.Combobox(self.master, values=mouths, width=10)
        self.combo_mouth.current(datetime.now().month - 1)

        self.combo_year = ttk.Combobox(self.master, values=years, width=5)
        self.combo_year.current(years.index(datetime.now().year))

        self.register_button = MyButton(self.master, text='Criar tarefa',
                                        command=self.create_task)

        self.description_box_title = MyLabel(self.master,
                                             text='Task description:',
                                             font='Tahoma 10 bold')
        self.description_box = ScrolledText(self.master, font='Consolas 9',
                                            width=60, height=10)

        # Place Widgets
        self.title_radio.place(x=10, y=10)
        self.radio1.place(x=150, y=10)
        self.radio2.place(x=210, y=10)
        self.radio3.place(x=285, y=10)

        self.title_entry.place(x=10, y=35)
        self.entry.place(x=150, y=35)

        self.title_combo_subjects.place(x=10, y=60)
        self.combo_subjects.place(x=150, y=60)

        self.title_date.place(x=10, y=85)
        self.combo_day.place(x=150, y=85)
        self.combo_mouth.place(x=190, y=85)
        self.combo_year.place(x=271, y=85)

        self.register_button.place(x=360, y=122)

        self.description_box_title.place(x=10, y=125)
        self.description_box.place(x=10, y=150)

    def create_task(self):
        """Create the task object and update the '
        MainWindow.tasks_widget(tk.Listbox)'."""
        new_task = Task(subject=self.combo_subjects.get(),
                        title=self.entry.get(),
                        day=self.combo_day.get(),
                        month=self.combo_mouth.get(),
                        year=self.combo_year.get(),
                        category=self.radio_var.get(),
                        description=self.description_box.get('1.0', 'end'))

        app.tasks_widget.delete(0, 'end')

        open_tasks.insert(0, new_task)
        open_tasks.sort(key=lambda task: task.full_date)
        for task in open_tasks:
            app.tasks_widget.insert('end', task)
        with open(file_open_tasks, 'wb') as outfile:
            pickle.dump(open_tasks, outfile, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        self.close_window()

    def close_window(self):
        app.add_button['state'] = 'active'
        app.sub_button['state'] = 'active'
        app.done_button['state'] = 'active'
        app.view_button['state'] = 'active'
        app.combo_confirm['state'] = 'active'
        self.master.destroy()


class EndTaskWindow:
    """Launch the window for end a task.

    Invoked from MainWindow.done_button -> returns the current selection on
    the MainWindow.tasks_widget
    -> task_index -> EndTaskWindow.__init__.
    """

    def __init__(self, master, task_index):
        self.master = master
        if task_index != ():
            self.task_index = task_index
            self.task = open_tasks[task_index[0]]

            master.title('Finalizar Tarefa')
            master.minsize(width=250, height=190)
            master.maxsize(width=250, height=190)
            master.geometry('+500+200')
            master.iconbitmap(icon_windows)
            master.configure(bg=bg_std)
            master.attributes('-topmost', True)
            master.focus()
            master.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.close_window)

        # Setup Widgets
        self.title_info = MyLabel(self.master, text='Dados da Atividade',
                                  font='Tahoma 14 bold')
        self.info_label_header = MyLabel(self.master,
                                         text='Tipo:\nTítulo:\nMatéria:'
                                              '\nData:',
                                         justify='left',
                                         font='Tamoha 10 bold')
        self.info_label = MyLabel(self.master, justify='left',
                                  font='Tahoma 10 italic',
                                  text='{}\n{}\n{}\n{}'.format(
                                      self.task.category, self.task.title,
                                      self.task.subject,
                                      self.task.full_date))
        self.title_combo_grades = MyLabel(self.master,
                                          text='Insira a menção final:',
                                          font='Tahoma 11 bold')
        self.combo_grades = ttk.Combobox(self.master, values=grades, width=3)
        self.finish_button = MyButton(self.master, text='Finalizar',
                                      command=lambda: self.end_task(
                                          self.combo_grades.get()),
                                      anchor='center')

        # Place Widgets
        self.title_info.place(x=10, y=10)

        self.info_label_header.place(x=10, y=40)
        self.info_label.place(x=75, y=40)

        self.title_combo_grades.place(x=10, y=125)
        self.combo_grades.place(x=180, y=127)
        self.finish_button.place(x=95, y=155)

    def end_task(self, grade):
        """Set the task as done.

        self.finish_button -> returns the current selection in
        self.combo_grades(tk.Combobox)

        Define task.is_done as True and grade.
        Remove this object from the list: open_task, append to list:
        ended_tasks
        """
        self.task.is_done = True
        self.task.grade = grade
        self.close_window()
        print(self.task.grade)
        print(self.task.is_done)
        ended_tasks.append(self.task)
        open_tasks.remove(self.task)

        app.tasks_widget.delete(0, 'end')

        for task in open_tasks:
            app.tasks_widget.insert('end', task)

        with open(file_open_tasks, 'wb') as outfile:
            pickle.dump(open_tasks, outfile, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

    def close_window(self):
        self.master.destroy()


class ViewTaskWindow:
    def __init__(self, master, task_index):
        self.master = master
        if task_index != ():
            self.task_index = task_index
            self.task = open_tasks[task_index[0]]
            master.title('Finalizar Tarefa')
            master.minsize(width=500, height=450)
            master.maxsize(width=500, height=450)
            master.geometry('+500+75')
            master.iconbitmap(icon_windows)
            master.configure(bg=bg_std)
            master.attributes('-topmost', True)
            master.focus()
            master.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.close_window)

            if self.task.description == '\n':
                self.description = 'Nothing to show'
            else:
                self.description = self.task.description

            # Setup Widgets
            self.title_info = MyLabel(self.master, text='Task information',
                                      font='Tahoma 14 bold')
            self.info_label_header = MyLabel(self.master,
                                             text='Type:\nTitle:\nSubject:'
                                                  '\nDate:',
                                             justify='left',
                                             font='Tamoha 10 bold')
            self.date_text = str(self.task.full_date).split(' ')
            self.info_label = MyLabel(self.master, justify='left',
                                      font='Tahoma 10 italic',
                                      text='{}\n{}\n{}\n{}'.format(
                                          self.task.category, self.task.title,
                                          self.task.subject,
                                          self.date_text[0]))

            self.description_title = MyLabel(self.master,
                                             text='Task description:',
                                             font='Tahoma 11 bold')
            self.description_label = MyLabel(self.master,
                                             text=self.description,
                                             font='Consolas 9', justify='left')

            self.description_text = ScrolledText(self.master, width=60,
                                                 height=20, font='Consolas 9')
            self.description_text.insert('1.0', self.description)
            self.description_text['state'] = 'disable'

            # Place Widgets
            self.title_info.place(x=10, y=10)

            self.info_label_header.place(x=10, y=40)
            self.info_label.place(x=75, y=40)

            self.description_title.place(x=10, y=120)
            self.description_text.place(x=10, y=150)
            # self.description_label.place(x=10, y=150)

    def close_window(self):
        self.master.destroy()


class SubjectWindow:
    """Launch the window with all completed tasks of specified subject

    Invoke by MainApplication.combo_confirm(tk.Button) ->
    returns the selection on MainApplication.combo_subjects
    -> subject -> SubjectWindow.__init__.
    """

    def __init__(self, master, subject):
        if subject in my_subjects:
            self.master = master
            self.subject = subject
            self.text_tasks_label = ''
            app.combo_confirm['state'] = 'disabled'
            master.title(subject)
            master.geometry('800x400')
            master.iconbitmap(icon_windows)
            master.configure(bg=bg_std)
            master.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.close_window)
        else:
            master.destroy()

        # Setup Widgets
        self.title = MyLabel(self.master,
                             text=self.subject,
                             font='Tahoma 15 bold')
        self.label1 = MyLabel(self.master,
                              text='Bases Tecnológicas',
                              font='Tahoma 12 bold')
        self.label2 = MyLabel(self.master,
                              text='Atividades e Menções',
                              font='Tahoma 12 bold')

        for task in ended_tasks:
            if task.subject == self.subject:
                print(task)
                print(task.str_task_complete())
                self.text_tasks_label += task.str_task_complete() + '\n'

        self.tasks_label = MyLabel(self.master,
                                   font='Tahoma 9',
                                   text='nothing here',
                                   justify='left')
        self.tasks_label.configure(text=self.text_tasks_label)

        # Place Widgets
        self.title.place(x=10, y=10)
        self.label2.place(x=10, y=55)
        self.tasks_label.place(x=10, y=80)

    def close_window(self):
        self.tasks_label.configure(text='')
        dump_pickle(file_ended_tasks, ended_tasks)
        self.master.destroy()
        app.combo_confirm['state'] = 'active'


username = getpass.getuser()
file_open_tasks = r'C:\Users\{}\AppData\Local\tasks_open.pkl'.format(username)
file_ended_tasks = r'C:\Users\{}\AppData\Local\tasks_ended.pkl'.format(
    username)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    open_tasks: list = load_pickle(file_open_tasks)
    ended_tasks: list = load_pickle(file_ended_tasks)
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```